# How can I remove Ubuntu from the UEFI boot options?

Tags: installation, boot, grub2, dual-boot, uefi

I have a Gigabyte motherboard. GA-Z77X-UD3H to be specific.

I recently installed Ubuntu and deleted it again, but it still shows up on the UEFI boot option even if **I removed all hard drives** connected to the motherboard.

So NO hard drives, even CD/DVDs, USB drives connected and I still see the Ubuntu boot option. Any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Boot a Linux emergency disc *in EFI mode* (the Ubuntu installer in its "try before installing" mode should work). You can then use the `efibootmgr` utility to delete the unwanted entry. You'll use `-v` to view the list of options and then a combination of `-b` and `-B` to eliminate the ones you don't want:

```
$ sudo efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0001,0003
Boot0000* rEFInd Boot Manager   HD(1,28,96000,bc34b60c-6611-492f-99b0-d2c37bd77f48)File(\EFI\refind\shim.efi)
Boot0001* fedora    HD(1,28,96000,bc34b60c-6611-492f-99b0-d2c37bd77f48)File(\EFI\fedora\grubx64.efi)
Boot0003* ubuntu    HD(1,28,96000,bc34b60c-6611-492f-99b0-d2c37bd77f48)File(EFI\Ubuntu\grubx64.efi)
$ sudo efibootmgr -b 3 -B
```

Some EFIs provide the ability to do this in their own user interfaces, too, but details vary greatly from one to another.

Comment: This worked for me, with a subtle exception. Instead of `fedora` identified by `Boot000`+digit, it ended with an uppercase 'A'. So I used it in final command of `sudo efibootmgr -b A -B`. It worked as expected, the fedora entry was no longer in the Windows boot options page.