# How to delete Refind entries

Tags: boot, uefi

I'm not sure which area this post would be appropriate, but here goes. I have attempted several different Linux distributions on my Macbook Pro Retina (10.1) before settling on Ubuntu 13.04 and I have noticed that some entries still remain in the Refind screen on system boot. The answer on this ([How can I remove Ubuntu from the UEFI boot options?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/263028/how-can-i-remove-ubuntu-from-the-uefi-boot-options)) page mentions using EFI bootmgr to show my entries and then delete them, but I don't really understand the resulting information. Just so you know, I am trying to remove a Manjaro entry and an Ubuntu entry (I have two on boot). Thank you for any help in advance.

```
sudo efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0080
Timeout: 5 seconds
BootOrder: 0080
Boot0080* Mac OS X  ACPI(a0341d0,0)PCI(1f,2)03120a00000000000000HD(2,64028,d634458,8430687d-0f85-4d7c-809b-e2b8078d1149)
Boot0081* Mac OS X  ACPI(a0341d0,0)PCI(1f,2)03120a00000000000000HD(1,28,64000,75fae237-ad7a-42bf-8691-5f73dab765df)File(\EFI\APPLE\FIRMWARE\ThorUtil.efi)-.o. .-.e.e. .-.f. .e.f.i.-.a.p.p.l.e.-.p.a.y.l.o.a.d.0.-.d.a.t.a...
Boot0082*   ACPI(a0341d0,0)PCI(1f,2)03120a00000000000000HD(2,64028,a7a3580,8430687d-0f85-4d7c-809b-e2b8078d1149)
BootFFFF*   ACPI(a0341d0,0)PCI(1f,2)03120a00000000000000HD(2,64028,10e15640,8430687d-0f85-4d7c-809b-e2b8078d1149)File(\System\Library\CoreServices\boot.efi)
```

Comment: @Rod Smith I wanted to add a bit more information. The specific entries that I want to delete that are shown when highlighting over the options are: "Boot EFI\manjaro_grub\grubx64_standalone.efi from EFI" and "Boot EFI\ubuntu\vmlinuz-3.8.0.19-generic from Macintosh HD". Both of these entries don't work, the manjaro one because I deleted the partitions which carried the information regarding the installation and I'm not sure why the ubuntu one doesn't work. The vmlinuz is the same version as the one I have currently.

Comment: Was this ever solved? If so how? I have the same issue.

Comment: I have the same problem. Ubuntu grub still shows up even though I have repartitioned the drive to a single Mac OS X partition.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use rEFInd but trim the number of options rEFInd itself shows, editing the entries as shown by `efibootmgr` won't work. In fact, using `efibootmgr` on a Mac is unlikely to have any desirable result, since Macs are weird in how they manage boot programs.

Instead, you need to manage your boot entries in one of the ways that rEFInd supports, such as:

- Deleting unwanted boot loader programs from the hard disk.
- Using the `dont_scan_volumes`, `dont_scan_dirs`, or `dont_scan_files` options in `refind.conf` to blacklist specific partitions, directories, or filenames from rEFInd's auto-detection.
- Deleting filesystem drivers to prevent rEFInd from scanning particular partitions.
- Adjusting the `scanfor` line in `refind.conf` to prevent scanning for certain broad classes of boot programs, such as BIOS-mode boot loaders (by removing `hdbios` from the list).
- Using `dd` to delete BIOS boot loaders from specific partitions or from the hard disk's MBR. This method is potentially dangerous, though.

Chances are one of the first two or three options will do what you want to do, but it's not clear from your description which one will work best for your situation. For instance, if you've deleted Manjaro or Ubuntu completely but still see boot options for them, chances are you've got leftover boot loaders for these OSes in the EFI System Partition (ESP), and deleting those files may be in order. OTOH, if you're seeing entries for an OS that you're booting in some other way, perhaps one of the `dont_scan` options would work better.

Note that in some cases rEFInd will produce multiple entries for one distribution, and these should *not* be trimmed. The reason is that rEFInd may detect multiple kernels. You can see the exact filename beneath the icon when you highlight an entry. If the filenames take the form `vmlinuz-{version}` but differ in their version numbers, this is what you're seeing. You should keep such multiple entries because sometimes a new kernel doesn't work properly, and having multiple kernels can therefore provide a fallback in case a new one doesn't work. If all your kernels work, you can get rid of older entries by uninstalling the older kernel package with `dpkg`, `apt-get`, `synaptic`, or some other tool. That's a variant on the first option. Just be sure that whatever's left actually boots successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having this same issue except I have Manjaro installed and removed Solus from a separate drive in my system. Refind still offers an entry for Solus as an option even though I thought I deleted the pertinent files from the EFI folder.

Comment: hi @schrobby, this is not technically an answer to the question, you can "comment" on the original post by using the Add Comment button underneath - this would be the appropriate place for a comment like this