# No grub, No Refind, No Boot on Surface pro 3 single install

Tags: grub2, uefi, refind

I at lost after trying everything but to no avail.
Installing Ubuntu on a Surface pro 3 (i7, 8gig of RAM) and I just can't seem to get either grub or rEFInd working, I'm installing as a single installation.
Secure boot is off and as well as tpd. wiping the harddrive but when i boot, i go straight to the bios (uefi).
I tried to live boot and do a boot-repair and i get an error regarding a locked ESP.
I gparted and wiped the partition - no good
I mounted /dev/sda1 and deleted the Microsoft folder as well as copied grub 64 to the boot/efi etc - no good
This is a single install that wipes everything out so why isn't it working?
driving me up the walls...

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Try this if ESP is sda1: Must be unmounted
`sudo dosfsck -t -a -w /dev/sda1`

Comment: These reports are rather old, but check [this question and answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/343085/unable-to-repair-boot-with-windows-8-and-ubuntu-13-04) and [this associated bug report.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1091477)

Comment: For future readers, this answer fixed it for me (boot the actual partition and then run `grub-install`): http://askubuntu.com/questions/546582/surface-pro-3-no-grub-menu/604238#604238