# Dualboot not working anymore with Windows 10 20H2

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-10

I received my new XPS 15 9500 today. I downloaded the media creation tool and created a new Windows 10 Boot Stick. Then I installed Windows 10 as normal.
After that I tried to install the Ubuntu 20.10 but stopped that after seeing the partition table.
Instead of showing the Windows partitions as NTFS they are shown as Bitlocker.
I started Windows 10, checked that it is Version 20H2 and also checked if Windows has enabled Bitlocker, but it has not. Windows 10 shows that Bitlocker is not active.
So I'm unable to resize this partition with Ubuntu and also think that I will not be able to access it from Ubuntu.
I'm aware that this is not primary problem of Ubuntu but I hope someone may have an advice for my how to work with Dual Boot as it has worked before...

Comment: If not seen by installer then Bitlocker must be on, or drives are still not AHCI? https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-installation-on-computers-running-windows-and-bitlocker-turned-on/15338 & https://superuser.com/questions/1280141/switch-raid-to-ahci-without-reinstalling-windows-10

Comment: As said. Windows 10 shows that Bitlocker is __not active__. The driver are AHCI. BIOS Default was Intel Raid and then the whole SSD was not seen by the Ubuntu installer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if the solution is a good idea. Nevertheless, the problem is solved.
I deactivated the TPM module in the BIOS.
Since the TPM module is also critically evaluated at https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module#Kritik I hope that this has no negative impact.

In any case, without an active TPM module, Windows 10 20H2 (Professional) does not convert partition C: into a bitlocker partition after installation.

To make it clear one more time... With TPM module active, Windows 10 20H2 converts it's partitions right after the first reboot after installation from the USB stick.
The Problem is, you can't deactivate Bitlocker in Windows, because it tells you, it's not active...